# Saving data from JSON end point

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, linkedin-api

I am trying to map over the returned json and save the id into profile/profiles. However it does not seem to be mapping over the the data correctly, `id:` `${ profile.id }` this bit needs to be changed? Any help is much appreciated.

Is their a online tool that can help with me this?

API request:

```
  // Grabs company data from the json url
  private getProfiles() {
    let config = {
      headers: {'Authorization':'Bearer AQVVEqNXTWVYPpPYivKNWVO8jsTx2eveV3kBg'}
    }
    axios
      .get("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/" + "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me", config)
      .then(response => 
          response.data.map(profile => ({
            id: `${ profile.id }`
         }))
        )
        .then(profiles => {
          this.setState({
            profiles
          });
        })
      // We can still use the `.catch()` method since axios is promise-based
      .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
  }
```

Json data returned:

```
{
    "localizedLastName": "King",
    "id": "fm0B3D6y3I",
    "localizedFirstName": "Benn"
}
```

When I console log the response.data
[image]

Comment: check what's in response.data then you'll know how to access what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only data returned from your endpoint is the JSON you posted, then you don't have an array to map over.

You have a single object.

I've never used the `axios` library before, but looking at the source code response.data should be the JSON-parsed responseText from the XHR request:

https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/4f189ec80ce01a0275d87d24463ef12b16715d9b/lib/adapters/xhr.js#L51-L53

https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/4f189ec80ce01a0275d87d24463ef12b16715d9b/lib/defaults.js#L61

And now I see that you have posted `response.data` and it matches what I'd expect.

With that in mind I'd suggest handling it like this:

```
 // Grabs company data from the json url
  private getProfiles() {
    let config = {
      headers: {'Authorization':'Bearer AQVVEqNXTWVYPpPYivKNWVO8jsTx2eveV3kBg'}
    }
    axios
      .get("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/" + "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me", config)
      .then(response => ({
            id: profile.id
         }))
        .then(profiles => {
          this.setState({
            profiles
          });
        })
      // We can still use the `.catch()` method since axios is promise-based
      .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
  }
```

What you're getting back is a single profile though.  If you need `profiles` to be an array you'll need to put the response in an array.

Answer (score -1):

I don't get it, what you are trying to do. In the map you have a callback function, but as I see you wrote there an object. If you are wanting to rewrite the current profile's id then write this:

```
 response.data.map(profile => ({
    profile.id = `${ profile.id }`;
 }))
```

But if you want it to make a variable then this:

```
 response.data.map(profile => ({
   let id = `${ profile.id }`;
 }))
```